# Include multiple parameters inside SAML RelayState parameter

Tags: url, parameters, saml-2.0

Basically have an issue when I set the RelayState parameter to /test/example?key=value&key1=value1 , key1=value1 is being split away from the RelayState parameter instead of being included in it like "/test/example?key=value&key1=value1".  I would be grateful for any assistance.  Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the problem is that the relay state is not URL encoded which is has to be. What software are you using to do SAML communication? Are you using a pre build application or building something yourself?

Comment: OP, just for some basic feedback, as you are new here at SE. It's way more helpful for you (and everyone else) if you provide more than what you have. What software package, authentication platform, or SAML library you are using to build your connection, what you've tried thus far, errors you're getting, etc. That makes it so everyone can benefit from both your question and the answers you get. I'll remove my downvote if you fix your question.

Comment: I obviously came up short on information needed here....my bad.  It was communication from Salesforce to Okta for a custom sso integration through apex code.  I resolved this myself, basically when you build the page reference in apex code, you should only use the base url in the constructor, no parameters.  Then, you add the parameters to the Page Reference's parameter map variable.  That way the parameter is not split.  Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For anybody else wondering about chopped off parameters, be sure to URLEncode the query string: 
 ❌ Don't do: /test/example?key=value&key1=value1
- ✅ Instead do:  **/test/example?key=value%26key1=value1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this myself, basically when you build the page reference in apex code, you should only use the base url in the constructor, no parameters. Then, you add the parameters to the Page Reference's parameter map variable. That way the parameter is not split. Thanks!